# Callback not returning

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am for some reason seeing the last callback hit even though it does get inside that first if statement.  Shouldn't it return in that first if when I do response(res)?  Well it's not.  For some reason it still continues on and hits the second response(res):

```
function find(response){
    var res = {};
    res.statusCode = 200;
    var data = _gateway.find();

    if(!data){
        res.statusCode = 204;
        res.body = null;

        console.log("SETTING RESPONSE BODY TO NULL");
        response(res);
    }

    console.log("SHHHHHHHHHHHHHOULD NOT GET HERE");
    res.body = data;

    response(res);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the callback doesn't mean that the current function will cease execution at that point. It is the same as calling some other function. In your case, once the callback function returns a value, the control gets transferred to the `find` function only and it continues to execute the rest of the statements.

To fix this, you need to return from the `find` immediately after the callback returns, like this

```
...
if(!data){
    res.statusCode = 204;
    res.body = null;

    console.log("SETTING RESPONSE BODY TO NULL");
    response(res);
    return;    // return from the `find` function
}
...
```

You can even return the result of `response`, like this

```
return response(res);
```

so that the control will be transferred immediately from the `find` function.

Answer (score 0):

After response(res) put return statement, otherwise it will try to execute remaining statements or put it in else part.